# looking for shell / perl script to capture the folder time stamp and the files inside the folder

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I am looking for script to capture the folder time stamp and the files inside the folder

Example: I have a folder *Cform12* with files inside say *note1.txt* , *note2.rtf* , *note3.ldt*

```
ls -lrt will generate drwxr-xr-x 5 r12applprd dba   4096 Dec  4 02:31 Cform12
```

and

```
ls -lrt SCF6761-PROD will generate 

total 12
-rwxr-xr-x  3 r12applprd dba 4096 Dec  4 02:30 note1.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  3 r12applprd dba 4096 Dec  4 02:30 note2.rtf
-rwxr-xr-x 26 r12applprd dba 4096 Dec  4 02:31 note3.ldt
```

Now i have output as

```
Dec  4 02:31 , Cform12 , note1.txt
Dec  4 02:31 , Cform12 , note2.txt
Dec  4 02:31 , Cform12 , note3.txt
```

Need help me with the shell or perl script for the same.

Comment: Have you used awk for column splitting?

Answer (score 1):

I think this script will help you if my understanding is correct..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path="/var/inner";#directory absolute path
my $mtime=(stat $path)[9];
my $name=`basename $path`;
chomp($name);
$mtime= localtime($mtime);
$mtime=`echo "$mtime" | awk '{print  \$2 , \$3, \$4}'`;
chomp($mtime);
my @files = glob("$path/*");
foreach my $file(@files){

        print "$mtime , $name , ".`basename $file`;


}
```

The script below does the same but recursively. Is this what you want?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path="/export/home/tarumugam/shellshop";#directory absolute path
sub rotator{
        (my $path)=@_;
        my $mtime=(stat $path)[9];
        my $name=`basename $path`;
        chomp($name);
        $mtime= localtime($mtime);
        $mtime=`echo "$mtime" | awk '{print  \$2 , \$3, \$4}' 2> /dev/null`;
        chomp($mtime);
        my @files = glob("$path/*");
        foreach my $file(@files){
                if(-f $file){
                        print "$mtime , $name , ".`basename $file`;
                }else{

                        rotator($file);

                }


        }
}

rotator($path);
```

Comment: Hi This is some what closer to what i am looking for but not exact solution i want to list all the files inside the /var/inner and the timestamp for the folder that it contains example if /var/inner has files a,b and folders f1,f2 and files inside folders f1 as a1 andf2 as a2 then i want the output to be

timestamp of inner, inner ,a
timestamp of inner, inner ,b
timestamp of f1, f1 ,a1
timestamp of f2, f2 ,a2

Comment: you mean the timestamp will be inner directory timestamp right?

Comment: yes inned directory time stamp and the directory name also inner directory name but the filenames will be the fine names inside the inner directory. They may be inside 1 level or multiple level

Comment: done...there is small change in the above script..now check the new one

Comment: Hi Thiyagu thanks this is exactly i want however a small change i want the folder and its time stamp and the folder names just one level down the /export/home/tarumugam/shellshop however it should list files under al the subfolders.Sorry to ask so many changes i am new to perl.

example directory structure
/export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf432/mylog.log
/export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf432/packages/mypkg.pkg
/export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf432/xxkns/12.0.0/admin/sql/mytrg.trg
/export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf543/java/ob/ai/xte.xml

Comment: expected output is 

line1: timestamp of /export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf432 , scf432 , mylog.log

line2: timestamp of /export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf432 , scf432 , mypkg.pkg

line3: timestamp of /export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf432 , scf432 , mytrg.trg

line4: timestamp of /export/home/tarumugam/shellshop/scf543 , scf543 , xte.xml

Comment: Hi Thyagu,With your script i have managed to get what i am looking for thanks for all the help

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $dir = '/tmp/';
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
        next unless (-d "$dir/$file");
        my $fdir = "$dir/$file";
        print "$fdir\n";
        my $mtime=(stat $fdir)[9];
        $mtime= localtime($mtime);
        $mtime=`echo "$mtime" | awk '{print  \$2 , \$3, \$4}' 2> /dev/null`;
        chomp($mtime);
        my @files1 = `find $fdir -type f|awk -F"/" '{ print \$NF }'`;
        foreach my $fil(@files1){
        print "$mtime,$file,$fil";
        }
    }
    closedir(DIR);
    exit 0;

Answer (score 1):

I have created the following script to help with my question .Thanks to the contributors for all the directions

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = '/tmp/';
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
  next unless (-d "$dir/$file");
  my $fdir = "$dir/$file";
  print "$fdir\n";
  my $mtime = (stat $fdir)[9];
  $mtime = localtime($mtime);
  $mtime = echo "$mtime" | awk '{print  \$2 , \$3, \$4}' 2 > /dev/ null;
  chomp($mtime);
  my @files1 = find $fdir -type f | awk -F "/" '{ print \$NF }';
  foreach my $fil (@files1) { print "$mtime,$file,$fil"; }
}
closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
$ stat -c "%x" src; find src -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec basename '{}' \;
2013-12-03 22:39:42.911796567 -0500
UndirectedGraphClient.java
UndirectedGraph.java
Bag.java
```

A bash scripting guide could help you out a lot. Maybe take a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php ?

Comment: I do not have stat in my system.Also i do not want to restrict to one level or 2 level depth it should go to any level of depth. Also I want the out put in a specific format not as shown above. Please let me know if you have any other alternatives

Comment: [This SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17725526/2019415) on how to *Find a file that was created within 5 days of another* lists a few alternatives to `stat`. Formatting your output should not be difficult with "pure" `perl`: in your shell you will surely have `printf`, `awk` ... etc. if you take a shell command approach

Comment: @Shurane note that `stat` can be a different animal on OS/X, Linux, BSD, Solaris. `perl` has a `stat` function that might hide some of that I guess. I agree it seems like a simple shell task though.